# Polymorpishm in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I am studying inheritance and polymorphism in C++ and I came across this example:

```
class Parent
{
    public:
        void a()
        {
             std::cout << "parentA";
        }

        virtual void b()
        {
             std::cout<<"parentB";
        }
 };

 class Child : public Parent
 {
     public:
        void b()
        {
             std::cout<<"childB";
        }
 };
```

Then in main:

```
int main()
{
    Parent i= Child();
    i.b(); //why doesn't this give parentB?

    Parent *j= new Child();
    j->b();
}
```

The outputs are parentA and childB respectively but I can't understand why. (isn't b() overriding?)

Comment: Do you mean you see "parentB" and "childB"?

Comment: google the term "slicing"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have "sliced" the `Child` class into the `Parent` class. In order to access virtual methods, you need to store the instance polymorphically, like you have with your second example. Polymorphic variables are pointers and references.

Answer (score 3):

The first case should give `parentB`, since the object `i` has type `Parent`, not `Child`. The `Child` object is *sliced* - that is, its `Parent` subobject is copied to create `i` of type `Parent`, then the temporary `Child` is destroyed. You can often prevent confusing behaviour like this by making base classes *abstract* (that is, giving them *pure virtual* functions), so that they can't be instantiated.

The second case should give `childB`, since the object that `j` points to has dynamic type `Child`.